# Python 2.7 Selenium, Click on button while the page isn't fully load

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, click, element

Can you click on an element, while the page is not fully load but the element is already loaded/visible? If yes then how? If no then is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, you could set an explicit wait targetting the "**presence_of_element_located**" or "**visibility_of_element_located**" condition. However keep in mind that the action fired by the click on the element could be binded in many ways, and some of them could take place after the dom is ready (when the complete DOM is loaded altough not yet completely rendered).

Think at these scenarios:

1. The element has an "onClick" attribute which fire a javascript function: in thiw case, the action could take place before the complete load (but only if it not concern elements that are not rendered yet)
2. The element is an anchor with an "href" attribute with a plain url inside it: in this case I think it could be pretty safe to click before the complete load
3. The element has an action binded through javascript at some point: in this case you should check the js code to make sure the element has the action already binded when you want to click it.

Comment: Can you write an example piece of code? How would you write the explicit wait? Let's say I want to click on `driver.find_element_by_id('a')` , without waiting for the page to fully load. And let's say the element is an anchor with an "href" attribute.

Comment: Maybe I've been a little hasty: I forgot to say that selenium, for each "get" of an url, waits until the DOM is ready, to return the control to your script. Considering this, if the anchor in the website you are handling is not loaded AFTER the initial DOM (ie through an ajax call or any other client-side DOM manipulation) I think it's not possible to achieve what you want. Sorry.

Comment: Well, the actual website loads pretty quickly and can be used in about 6000ms but the driver waits till the ads from https://springserve.com to load which loads really slowly.

Comment: This changes a lot the scenario: if your problem is related to loading of unwanted contents like ADS, I suggest to switch to Firefox or Chrome (if you haven't done it yet) and install an ad-block extension to prevent them to load. If you script is targetted to a specific website, you could refine the algorithm of the extension to block every single ad in that website.